# Can I make a table sortable when it's populated by vue v-for?

Tags: vue.js, html-table

My client has asked me to make the following table sortable on all columns:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 18%">Customer/Supplier</th>
        <th style="width: 7%">Title</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">First Name</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Last Name</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Department</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Email Address</th>
        <th style="width: 15%">Main Phone</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Catetory</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">Position</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in SearchResultContactList" v-bind:key="item.ContactID" v-on:click="viewContact(item.ContactID)">
        <td>{{item.CustomerName}}{{item.SupplierName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.TitleName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.DepartmentName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.EmailAddress}}</td>
        <td>{{getContactMainPhoneNumber(item)}}</td>
        <td>{{item.CategoryName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Position}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I've tried this on the Last Name column

```
            <th data-field="LastName" data-sortable="true" style="width: 10%">Last Name</th>
```

However, it doesn't work.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: `SearchResultContactList` already is sorted in some way. To make the table sortable, add a click handler to a header field . When clicked, sort `SearchResultContactList` accordingly (Title clicked, sort it by Title). Vue will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest what the comment suggested, so I built a scaled back sample component to demonstrate.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   contacts: [
      {
        firstName: 'Aaa',
        lastName: 'Www'
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Lll',
        lastName: 'Mmm'
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Zzz',
        lastName: 'Bbb'
      },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    sortContacts(property) {
      this.contacts.sort((a, b) => (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : -1);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
th {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <div class="sort-table-by-columns">
    <div class="row"><div class="col-md-6">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th @click="sortContacts('firstName')">FIRST NAME</th>
            <th @click="sortContacts('lastName')">LAST NAME</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(contact, index) in contacts" :key="index">
            <td>{{ contact.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ contact.lastName }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```